# Creating a script for a custom field output in ABAQUS

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus

I want to create a custom field output in ABAQUS. For the purpose of proof on concept, I want to display the maximum shear stress as calculated from the Mohrs circle, as discussed [here](http://www.efunda.com/formulae/solid_mechanics/mat_mechanics/calc_principal_stress.cfm) for a 2D shell.

I have my code below for reference:

```
from abaqusConstants import *
from odbAccess import *
from math import *
from copy import deepcopy
from caeModules import *
from driverUtils import executeOnCaeStartup

# ******************************************************************************
#Items in this box require student input when changing files

#must input the file path here.
odbPath = "/home/MohrsTest.odb"

odb = session.openOdb(name=odbPath, readOnly=FALSE)
odb = session.odbs[odbPath]
#this will display the instance names. Please choose one to input in line 14.
print odb.rootAssembly.instances.keys()
grout_instance = odb.rootAssembly.instances['SQUARE-1']
# ******************************************************************************
keys = odb.steps.keys()
for key in keys:
    step = odb.steps[key]
    for frame in step.frames:
        print frame.description
        Stress = frame.fieldOutputs['S']
        #try modifying scalar fields rather than creating new var element by element.
        S11=Stress.getScalarField(componentLabel="S11")
        S22=Stress.getScalarField(componentLabel="S22")
        S12=Stress.getScalarField(componentLabel="S12")
        TauMax=((S11+S22)*0.5+sqrt(power((S11-S22)/2, 2)+power(S12, 2)))-((S11+S22)*0.5-sqrt(power((S11-S22)/2, 2)+power(S12, 2)))/2
        ThetaP=(atan2(2 * S12, (S11 - S22))/2) * 180/pi
        frame.FieldOutput(name='Tau Max', description='Max Tau from Mohrs circle',field=TauMax)
        frame.FieldOutput(name='Theta P', description='Thetap as measured ccw from 0 degree',field=Thetap)
odb.save()
odb.close()
#  must re - open the output database to see the new custom field output
```

Abaqus throws an error immediately upon trying to calculate TauMax because of "Type Error: A float is required." However, I tried using "Tools->Field Outputs-> Create from Fields" and then created a field output in the cae for the individual frame. 
If I look at the replay file for this action, I can see the following code:

```
s1f1_S = session.odbs['/home/MohrsTest.odb'].steps['Step-1'].frames[1].fieldOutputs['S']
tmpField = (((s1f1_S.getScalarField(componentLabel="S11")+\
    s1f1_S.getScalarField(componentLabel="S22"))*0.5+sqrt(power((
    s1f1_S.getScalarField(componentLabel="S11")-s1f1_S.getScalarField(
    componentLabel="S22"))/2, 2)+power(s1f1_S.getScalarField(
    componentLabel="S12"), 2)))-((s1f1_S.getScalarField(componentLabel="S11")+\
    s1f1_S.getScalarField(componentLabel="S22"))*0.5-sqrt(power((
    s1f1_S.getScalarField(componentLabel="S11")-s1f1_S.getScalarField(
    componentLabel="S22"))/2, 2)+power(s1f1_S.getScalarField(
    componentLabel="S12"), 2))))/2
```

Thus, clearly math operations on a FieldObject must be possible. Why does my code not permit this?

I am happy to provide all .odb and .cae files for reference and verification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure native `Abaqus/CAE` scripts use `numpy` for math functions.  But `numpy.sqrt` gets overwritten by `math.sqrt` when you do `from math import *`.  `math.sqrt` can't handle the `numpy` array generated by `.getScalarField()`, and you get an error.

Comment: That was my thinking too, but if you see my second code chunk, it does just that.

Comment: That second code chunk is directly from the ABAQUS replay file. Im happy to provide the whole replay file, but it doesnt import anything unusual. It has from abaqus import *...

Comment: I also think i tried numpy's square root in my code and it still broke, i can go back and check though

Comment: Did you try just not importing `math` in your script?

Comment: In your code S11 is a FieldOutput Object. This means that you are working with an proprietary Abaqus object and not with an numpy array nor a simple Python Array. Abaqus Python has by default a few mathematical functions for this type of object in the global namespace. If you import any module which has functions with same names, in your case math, in the global namespace these are overwritten and your script will fail. The standard math functions work on numbers not on FieldOutput Objects.